# Append new column to a Snowpark DataFrame with simple string

Tags: python, dataframe, snowpark

I've started using python Snowpark and no doubt missing obvious answers based on being unfamiliar to the syntax and documentation.
I would like to do a very simple operation: append a new column to an existing Snowpark DataFrame and assign with a simple string.
Any pointers to the documentation to what I presume is readily achievable would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by using the function *with_column* in combination with the *lit* function. The *with_column* function needs a Column expression and for a literal value this can be made with the *lit* function. see documentation here: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowpark/reference/python/api/snowflake.snowpark.functions.lit.html

```
from snowflake.snowpark.functions import lit 
snowpark_df = snowpark_df.with_column('NEW_COL', lit('your_string'))
```